# Pandas ValueError when creating series indexes from a list of pd.Index objects

Tags: python, pandas

When trying to create a pandas Series in the following way, I am receiving a ValueError:

```
indexes = [pd.Index([1]), pd.Index([2])]
pd.Series(
    ["a", "b"], 
    index=indexes
)
```

`ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (1)`

Is this expected/documented behaviour?

Tested on:

- python3.11/pandas1.5.1
- python3.9.13/pandas1.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using ?

```
indexes = [1,2]
pd.Series(
    ["a", "b"], 
    index=indexes
)
```

Comment: This is just  simplified example. Im not creating the indexes list like this in my actual code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).